# Is MDN wrong about the html main tag in their documentation?

Tags: html

I was stumbling about the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main) documents and saw that they said it was ok to use the main tag in article elements, while [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_main.asp) says it should not be a decedent at all within the article element.

MDN:

> You can use multiple `<main>` elements within the same page when it
>   makes sense to do so. For instance, if you have a page presenting
>   multiple articles (each inside an `<article>` element,

W3:

> **Note:** There must not be more than one `<main>` element in a document.
>   The `<main>` element must NOT be a descendant of an `<article>`, `<aside>`,
>   `<footer>`, `<header>`, or `<nav>` element.

I want others to help me confirm if this is right and if so how can I contact MDN about this? I looked at their [github](https://github.com/mdn/) and there is no place to report issues, or the [contact us](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/contact/) page is just about firefox, legalities of using the logo, or donating. Which is the right channel for the documentation support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the top infobox on the MDN page:

> Permitted parents: Any element that accepts flow content (WHATWG). However, the W3C specification doesn't allow `<main>` to be used as a descendent of `<article>`, `<aside>`, `<footer>`, `<header>`, or `<nav>`.

Basically, the W3C and WHATWG specifications disagree. Typically, the WHATWG spec is what browsers follow, though there isn't much reason to place a `<main>` as a descendent of one of the others listed.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Didn't even know there was a second specification group out there. Guess I should of read more rather than skim the top haha.

Comment: Yeah, it can be pretty complicated. Like I said, the WHATWG is normally what vendors implement, as the W3C changes some things that don't make much sense.

Comment: Yeah I saw the wikepedia page on the motivation to create WHATWG. Hoping we can agree on things more, or have a universal package install on browsers the vendors can use to keep specifications working the same.